# Neovim 0.17.5: bash command top failed tty get

Tags: neovim, external-command

please be gentle, I am trying to learn neovim, coming from vim

the command `:!top` executed inside neovim returns

```
top: failed tty get

shell returned 1
```

After googling, only search results from `fzf` github regarding kernel regression

https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/issues/1486

https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/issues/447

I have never used `fzf` in vim/linux before, I am also trying to use it later on in neovim

But trying out the command on `fzf` (after installing it), from [1486](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/issues/1486)

```
echo "hello" | fzf --preview 'echo {}'
```

in the terminal, it does not return any error. So I think the kernel regression issue is solved?

The OS I am using is Debian Buster.

I am not using `:terminal` or `Ctrl-Z` to use shell commands in my vim workflow.

If you find that the only way to use these programs is to use these two options in neovim, please let me know.

Comment: See https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/FAQ#-and-system-do-weird-things-with-interactive-processes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at `:help :!`. It says:

> The command runs in a non-interactive shell connected
>   to a pipe (not a terminal). Use :terminal to run an
>   interactive shell connected to a terminal.

As `top` requires a terminal, it can't be run this way.

Running `:!top` in Vim works as expected, so `:!` seems to be implemented differently in neovim.